# Formal implicit function theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have seen a lemma about formal series in the book Complex Projective Varieties by D. Mumford.

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i+(\text{higher order terms})\in \mathbb{C}[[X]]$$
and assume $a_1\not=0$. Then $f$ can he factored as:
$$f(X)=u(X_1,......,X_n)(X_1-g(X_2,......,X_n))$$
where $u(0)=0,\ g(0)\not=0$.

I have tried the case of n=2. It's quite complicated so that I can't get further.

I hope someone could give me a simple solution.

Comment: Maybe Mumford, but not Zariski.

Comment: I know it's a late response, but have a look at the proof of Weierstrass Preparation Theorem, you might find that quite helpful.